# NSArray full of NSDictionaries. How to find index of object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I have an `array` which is filled with `NSDictionaries`. I want to find the `index` of one of the dictionary, but what I know about this dictionary is only a `value` for key `@"name".` 
How do I do it ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Find index of first dictionary in `theArray` whose value for `@"name"` is `theValue`:

```
NSUInteger index = [theArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:
        ^BOOL(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
        {
            return [[dict objectForKey:@"name"] isEqual:theValue];
        }
];
```

`index` will be `NSNotFound` if no matching object is found.

Comment: I guess NSPredicate is the thing to use.

Comment: @Ashishail: Predicates are used for *filtering* arrays, i.e. returning a *new array* with all objects that match a condition. If only the index of the first match is needed, I think that `indexOfObjectPassingTest` is more effective.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution ! But do you know why my index is always a huge number like 2147483647 ?

Comment: @SmartTree: 2147483647 = 0x7FFFFFFF is `NSNotFound`.

Comment: Does this block not stop after YES is returned? Is that why there is the bool *stop pointer? I can't see a reason why you'd want to stop the block before finding the index nor keep it running after finding it?

Comment: @Rambatino: This method *does* stop the iteration as soon as a match is found. The block could set the stop parameter to NO to prematurely stop the iteration, in that case the method would return NSNotFound. As an example, you could stop the iteration if no match is found in the first 1000 elements. – Does that answer your question?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the elegantly simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSArray *temp = [allList valueForKey:@"Name"];
 NSInteger indexValue = [temp indexOfObject:YourText];
 NSString *name = [[allList objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"Name"]
```