# How to retrieve single value from NSDictonary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Well I Have a NSDictonary Like this

```
NSDictonary *dict = [responseobject valueForKey:@"stu"]; //response object is json data
dict  = {
       age  = 12,
       name = xyz,
       class= 10

     },

     {
      age  = 13,
       name = abc,
       class= 10

     }.......
```

Now I want another NSDictonary in which I want only one object which have name abc

```
newDict = {
     age = 13,
     name = abc,
     class=10
    }
```

How can I do this.

Comment: `dict  = {
       age  = 12,
       name = xyz,
       class= 10

     },

     {
      age  = 13,
       name = abc,
       class= 10

     }.......` is a dict or array?

Comment: Your first object is not a dictionary...

Comment: yes i am getting it via json

Comment: @deadbeef i have updated my question

Comment: You are still having an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404722/nsarray-full-of-nsdictionaries-how-to-find-index-of-object

Comment: log the dict what does it contains?

Answer (score 1):

First off you have an array of dictionaries here.

You can use `NSPredicate` to filter out just the item you need.

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@".name == %@",@"abc"];
 NSArray *newArray = [dict filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predictae];
```

and then in your `newArray` you have the items matching the predicate.